# Restart loop when it ends

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

```js
 let options = document.getElementsByClassName("option");
 console.log(options);
 var i = 1;  


for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++){ 
        options[i].classList.remove("active")
        setTimeout(function () {   
            if(i!=0){
                console.log(options[i-1].classList.remove("active"))
            }
            console.log(options[i].classList.add("active"))
           
         }, i*3000)
        
}



function changeItem(item){
    item.classList.add("active")
}
```

```css
body {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
            flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  }
  body .credit {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    color: #000;
  }
  body .options {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
            flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-align: stretch;
            align-items: stretch;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 600px;
    max-width: 900px;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
    height: 400px;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 718px) {
    body .options {
      min-width: 520px;
    }
    body .options .option:nth-child(5) {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 638px) {
    body .options {
      min-width: 440px;
    }
    body .options .option:nth-child(4) {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 558px) {
    body .options {
      min-width: 360px;
    }
    body .options .option:nth-child(3) {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 478px) {
    body .options {
      min-width: 280px;
    }
    body .options .option:nth-child(2) {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  body .options .option {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    min-width: 60px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: var(--optionBackground, var(--defaultBackground, #E6E9ED));
    background-size: auto 120%;
    background-position: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.05, 0.61, 0.41, 0.95);
    transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.05, 0.61, 0.41, 0.95);
  }
  body .options .option:nth-child(1) {
    --defaultBackground:#ED5565;
  }
  body .options .option:nth-child(2) {
    --defaultBackground:#FC6E51;
  }
  body .options .option:nth-child(3) {
    --defaultBackground:#FFCE54;
  }
  body .options .option:nth-child(4) {
    --defaultBackground:#2ECC71;
  }
  body .options .option:nth-child(5) {
    --defaultBackground:#5D9CEC;
  }
  body .options .option:nth-child(6) {
    --defaultBackground:#AC92EC;
  }
  body .options .option.active {
    -webkit-box-flex: 10000;
            flex-grow: 10000;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
            transform: scale(1);
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    /*&:active {
       transform:scale(0.9);
    }*/
  }
  body .options .option.active .shadow {
    box-shadow: inset 0 -120px 120px -120px black, inset 0 -120px 120px -100px black;
  }
  body .options .option.active .label {
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
  }
  body .options .option.active .label .info > div {
    left: 0px;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  body .options .option:not(.active) {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
            flex-grow: 1;
    border-radius: 30px;
  }
  body .options .option:not(.active) .shadow {
    bottom: -40px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -120px 0px -120px black, inset 0 -120px 0px -100px black;
  }
  body .options .option:not(.active) .label {
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
  }
  body .options .option:not(.active) .label .info > div {
    left: 20px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  body .options .option .shadow {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 120px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.05, 0.61, 0.41, 0.95);
    transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.05, 0.61, 0.41, 0.95);
  }
  body .options .option .label {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.05, 0.61, 0.41, 0.95);
    transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.05, 0.61, 0.41, 0.95);
  }
  body .options .option .label .icon {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
            flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    min-width: 40px;
    max-width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: white;
    color: var(--defaultBackground);
  }
  body .options .option .label .info {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
            flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: white;
    white-space: pre;
  }
  body .options .option .label .info > div {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.05, 0.61, 0.41, 0.95), opacity 0.5s ease-out;
    transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.05, 0.61, 0.41, 0.95), opacity 0.5s ease-out;
  }
  body .options .option .label .info .main {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }
  body .options .option .label .info .sub {
    -webkit-transition-delay: .1s;
            transition-delay: .1s;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="options">
        <div class="option active" style="--optionBackground:url(https://66.media.tumblr.com/6fb397d822f4f9f4596dff2085b18f2e/tumblr_nzsvb4p6xS1qho82wo1_1280.jpg);">
           <div class="shadow"></div>
           <div class="label">
              <div class="icon">
                 <i class="fas fa-walking"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="info">
                 <div class="main">Blonkisoaz</div>
                 <div class="sub">Omuke trughte a otufta</div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="option" style="--optionBackground:url(https://66.media.tumblr.com/8b69cdde47aa952e4176b4200052abf4/tumblr_o51p7mFFF21qho82wo1_1280.jpg);">
           <div class="shadow"></div>
           <div class="label">
              <div class="icon">
                 <i class="fas fa-snowflake"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="info">
                 <div class="main">Oretemauw</div>
                 <div class="sub">Omuke trughte a otufta</div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="option" style="--optionBackground:url(https://66.media.tumblr.com/5af3f8303456e376ceda1517553ba786/tumblr_o4986gakjh1qho82wo1_1280.jpg);">
           <div class="shadow"></div>
           <div class="label">
              <div class="icon">
                 <i class="fas fa-tree"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="info">
                 <div class="main">Iteresuselle</div>
                 <div class="sub">Omuke trughte a otufta</div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="option" style="--optionBackground:url(https://66.media.tumblr.com/5516a22e0cdacaa85311ec3f8fd1e9ef/tumblr_o45jwvdsL11qho82wo1_1280.jpg);">
           <div class="shadow"></div>
           <div class="label">
              <div class="icon">
                 <i class="fas fa-tint"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="info">
                 <div class="main">Idiefe</div>
                 <div class="sub">Omuke trughte a otufta</div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="option" style="--optionBackground:url(https://66.media.tumblr.com/f19901f50b79604839ca761cd6d74748/tumblr_o65rohhkQL1qho82wo1_1280.jpg);">
           <div class="shadow"></div>
           <div class="label">
              <div class="icon">
                 <i class="fas fa-sun"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="info">
                 <div class="main">Inatethi</div>
                 <div class="sub">Omuke trughte a otufta</div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
     </div>

     <a href="http://victorofvalencia-blog.tumblr.com" target="_blank" class="credit">Photos from Victor of Valencia on tumblr</a>
     <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I took this animation from codepen , initially it executes on clicks only but I wanted to execute it after 3s. So I added a for loop.

I am changing classes of each element after 3000ms, what I want is when loops ends or reach last element it should restart from beginning. I tired setting `i = 0` when `i` is last element of array, but it didn't work somehow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That code starts a bunch of timeouts, the first will trigger rightaway, the next after 3000 milliseconds, the 3rd after 6000, and so on. To get the entire thing to repeat, you have to combine setTimeout and setInterval, you basically need to wrap the code inside the setTimeout function in a setInterval call with a delay of 15000. (5 options times 3000). There are of course better ways to do this: use a single setInterval that keeps track of the current image and acts accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use setInterval instead of setTimeOut inside a for loop.

```
 let options = document.getElementsByClassName("option");
 var i = 1;
 setInterval(function () {
  if (i === 5) {
    options[i - 1].classList.remove("active")
    i = 0
  }
  if (i != 0) {
    if (i === 5) {
      options[i].classList.remove("active")
    }
    options[i - 1].classList.remove("active")
  }
  options[i].classList.add("active")
  i++
 }, 3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't really need a cycle:

```
var i = 0, n = options.length;

function loop() {
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    options[i].classList.remove("active");
    i++;
    if (i == n) {
      i = 0;
    }
    options[i].classList.add("active"));
    loop();
  }, 3000);
}

if (n > 0) {
  // if there is at least one element then activate the first one
  options[i].classList.add("active"); 
  if (n > 1) {
    // if there are several elements run loop
    loop();
  }
}
```